# Shading between two curves using geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to reproduce the plot from the package survIDINRI using ggplot. Below it is an example presented in the documentation.

```
#--- sample data (pbc in survival package) ---
D=subset(pbc, select=c("time","status","age","albumin","edema","protime","bili"))
D$status=as.numeric(D$status==2)
D=D[!is.na(apply(D,1,mean)),]
mydata=D[1:100,]

t0=365*5
indata1=mydata; 
indata0=mydata[,-7]
covs1<-as.matrix(indata1[,c(-1,-2)])
covs0<-as.matrix(indata0[,c(-1,-2)])

#--- inference ---
x<-IDI.INF(mydata[,1:2], covs0, covs1, t0, npert=200) 

#--- Graphical presentation of the estimates ---
IDI.INF.GRAPH(x)
```

Editing the function IDI.INF.GRAPH, I wrote the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
s <- x$point$cc
event <- 1 - x$point$FX
nevent <- 1 - x$point$GX
Xlim <- c(min(s[event > 0.001 | nevent > 0.001]), 
          max(s[event < 0.999 | nevent < 0.999]))
Ylim <- c(0, 1)
class <- ifelse(nevent > event, "blue", "red")

data_plot <- data.frame(event, nevent, s, class, min = event, max = nevent)
data_plot <- data_plot %>% gather(key = curve, value = value, event:nevent)

gp <- ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = s, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = curve), size = 1.2)  +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = s, ymin = min, ymax = max, fill = class)) +
  scale_linetype("C.D.F.", labels = c("Event", "Non-Event")) +
  labs(y = "P(D < s)", x = "s") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw()
```

It seems geom_ribbon is not adequate since I have two non-continuous areas. Then I tried geom_polygon:

```
s <- x$point$cc
event <- 1 - x$point$FX
nevent <- 1 - x$point$GX
Xlim <- c(min(s[event > 0.001 | nevent > 0.001]), 
          max(s[event < 0.999 | nevent < 0.999]))
Ylim <- c(0, 1)
class <- ifelse(nevent > event, "blue", "red")

data_plot <- data.frame(event, nevent, s, class)
data_plot <- data_plot %>% gather(key = curve, value = value, event:nevent)

ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = s, y = value)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = curve), size = 1.2)  +
    geom_polygon(data = subset(data_plot, class == "blue"), 
                aes(x = s, y = value, group = class), fill = "blue") +
    geom_polygon(data = subset(data_plot, class == "red"), 
                aes(x = s, y = value), fill = "red") +
    scale_linetype("C.D.F.", labels = c("Event", "Non-Event")) +
    labs(y = "P(D < s)", x = "s") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme_bw()
```

I know that I am not using geom_polygon properly, although I could not find a solution yet. Any ideas?